# How to understand SequencedLambda(KafkaRunner) and DocumentPartition(DocumentLambda),and their related, in fluid-framework

Tags: fluid-framework

> https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/release/0.30/server/routerlicious/packages/lambdas-driver/src/kafka-service/README.md#L81

> source code of project

I found that there are two ways to manage Kafka Service,

DocumentLambda and KafkaRunner.

They are very similar, and I want to know more about the differences.
And the reason or the history of why it is like this

Answer (score 1):

We use a fixed number of Kafka partitions. So, a partition is shared by multiple documents. The DocumentLambda is responsible for routing the messages inside a partition to corresponding lambda handler. It contains a HashMap where key is "tenantId/documentId". For every incoming message, it looks up those fields to determine the lambda associated with that message.

Comment: I feel sorry that I did not express my question well.
Right now, I think ScriptoriumLambda handles messages directly. Logic code is in the `routerlicious/packages/lambdas/src/scriptorium/lambda.ts`

Comment: And DocumentLambda will handle in DocumentPartition. DocumentPartition actual logic processing is in `routerlicious/packages/routerlicious/SRC/deli/index.ts` or someone like.

Comment: ScriptoriumLambda and DocumentLambda seem to differ only in code location